# Using API to extract tagged answers in SurveyMonkey

Tags: r, surveymonkey

In the Analyze page of SurveyMonkey you are able to add tags to open ended responses. Is there a way to extract these tags from SurveyMonkeys API? Specifically through R.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/cloudyr/Rmonkey? It hasn't been updated recently, but perhaps it still works. Other than that, have you looked at their [API docs](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/)?

Comment: If you want to get a tested answer then you may need to supply authorization specifics. You know, ....  like code, man. Do they, for instance, have a trial option? Or can you offer a password that you will then change after 3 hours. (The Rmonkey package does still install and load but is is way out of date, having been archived in 2016.)